# Bootstrap Minimum Height for a Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a banner in my page. I managing the design with bootstrap. The image with the id ”mybanner” is created dynamically from the code. So there are times that my code may not have at all the image element.
I would like to specify a minimum height for the div id ” myhorizontalbanner” so if there is not present at all the image element to display as banner the div id ” myhorizontalbanner” colored with red color.

My code when the image is there

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 bg-red-banner">
      <div class="row" id="myhorizontalbanner">
        <img id="mybanner" src="images/mybannerimage.jpg" class="img-fluid" />  <!--This Image 
         element is comming dynamically-->          
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code when I dont have image

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 bg-red-banner">
      <div class="row" id="myhorizontalbanner">
                  
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with min-height ?
For example:

```
#myhorizontalbanner {
  min-height: 150px;
}
```